# How can I upload vendor/ folder when composer.lock changes through github action using SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1

Tags: continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, github-actions, git-ftp

I was trying to push a laravel app to a ftp server through github action. Here is the snippet is from my deploy.yml file.

```
jobs:
  Deployment:
    name: Deploy Action
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
          
      - name: Create env file
        run: |
            touch .env
            echo APP_NAME=MyAppName >> .env
            echo APP_ENV=production >> .env
            echo APP_DEBUG=false >> .env
            echo LOG_CHANNEL=daily >> .env
            echo DB_DATABASE=${{ secrets.DEV_DB_DATABASE }} >> .env
            echo DB_USERNAME=${{ secrets.DEV_DB_USERNAME }} >> .env
            echo DB_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DEV_DB_PASSWORD }} >> .env
            echo "!.env" > .git-ftp-include
      
      - name: Cache dependencies
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ~/.composer/cache/files
          key: dependencies-composer-${{ hashFiles('composer.json') }}

      - name: Setup PHP
        uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
        with:
          php-version: 7.3
          extensions: dom, curl, libxml, mbstring, zip, pcntl, pdo, sqlite, pdo_sqlite
          coverage: none

      - name: Install Composer dependencies
        run: composer install --prefer-dist --no-interaction --no-suggest
        
      - name: Adding Vendor
        run: echo "!vendor/" > .git-ftp-include
      
      - name: FTP Deploy Action
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1
        with:
          ftp-server: ftp://${{ secrets.DEV_FTP_SERVER }}
          ftp-username: ${{ secrets.DEV_FTP_USERNAME }}
          ftp-password: ${{ secrets.DEV_FTP_PASSWORD }}
```

Every time when the job runs, it uploads whole vendor/ directory on FTP server. It takes a lot of time when the vendor folder uploads. How can I just upload only changes in vendor/ directory, or if only composer.lock get modified it will upload vendor/.
Or how can I make it simple, fast and easy ?

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? How is this related to Composer itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace:

`run: echo "!vendor/" > .git-ftp-include`

for:

`run: echo "vendor/:composer.lock" > .git-ftp-include`

However keep in mind that this:

> will upload all files in the vendor folder, even those that are on the server already. And it will not delete files from that directory if local files are deleted.

That could be a problem in the case in which a package removes a local file in a new version release because the file would be kept on the server, possibly causing some conflicts.

See the docs [here](https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action#force-upload-specific-files).

Edit: If you have already committed the composer.lock file, And you want to reupload the vendor folder for the last time, make sure to change the .lock file. Maybe add a new line or space to it.